# Plot a graph using .NET

Tags: c#, graph

I need to read some data from an input file and plot a graph based on the inputs...

I want to plot a graph using visual C#. Is there any in-built functions to plot a graph in visual C#..
If not, how can I do that..

I wanted to create using asp.net

Comment: Using Windows Forms, Web Forms, or what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a pack of charting controls from MS, which can be used for creating graphs on winforms and ASP.NET.

You can download them [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en). And learn more [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart).

Answer (score 2):

Here is [OxyPlot](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/)

It supports different platforms and rendering targets (wpf, winforms, pdf, etc)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a web environment there are also lots of ways of drawing graphs directly in the browser, using the CANVAS element or SVG. I prefer [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has superb support for displaying graphs, and with a few lines of interop you can [display a .NET array using the Matlab runtimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654690/creating-a-graph-or-a-plot-from-a-c-console-app-using-matlab/7697583#7697583).

You could also use IronPython to call MatPlotLib.

Answer (score 0):

[WebControl](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting) will fit your needs