# Creating a graph or a plot from a C# console app, using Matlab?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, graph, matlab-deployment

If I have a two dimensional array in C#, how would I plot the contents of this array in Matlab, as a 2-D graph? I'm after an extension method, i.e.

```
my2DArray.PlotInMatlab();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got this working well in the end. Here is a sample graph, generated by a .NET 4.0 C# console app that calls a Matlab .m file:

[image]

The nice thing is that we can use all the power of Matlab for drawing graphs, with only a few lines of .NET.

How to do this in .NET:

6. Create a new .NET console app for C# in Visual Studio 2010, and change it to .NET 4.0 (right click on the project, select "Properties").

   11. .NET Main():

       ```
       using System;
       using System.Diagnostics;

       namespace MyPlotGraphUsingMatlabRuntimes
       {
           /// <summary>
           /// Display a graph in Matlab, from a .NET console app.
           /// </summary>
           class Program
           {
               static void Main(string[] args)
               {
                   var x = new double[100];
                   var y = new double[100];
                   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                       x[i] = i;
                       y[i] = 2 ^ i;
                   }
                   MyHelper.MyMatlab.MyGraph2D(x,y);
                   Console.Write("[any key to exit]");
                   Console.ReadKey();
               }
           }
       }
       ```
   12. .NET class that provides extension methods to do interop into Matlab (name the file `MyMatlab.cs`).

       ```
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
       namespace MyHelper
       {
           /// <summary>
           /// Collection of chained classes to make Matlab access easier.
           /// </summary>
           public static class MyMatlab
           {
               /// <summary>
               /// Returns a double in a format that can be passed into Matlab.
               /// </summary>
               /// <param name="toMatlab">Double to convert into a form we can pass into Matlab.</param>
               /// <returns>A double in Matlab format.</returns>
               public static MWNumericArray MyToMatlab(this double toMatlab)
               {
                   return new MWNumericArray(toMatlab);
               }
               /// <summary>
               /// Converts an array that contains a single Matlab return parameter back into a .NET double.
               /// </summary>
               /// <param name="toDouble">MWArray variable, returned from Matlab code.</param>
               /// <returns>.NET double.</returns>
               public static double MyToDouble(this MWArray toDouble)
               {
                   var matNumericArray = (MWNumericArray)toDouble;
                   return matNumericArray.ToScalarDouble();
               }
               /// <summary>
               /// Converts an array that contains multiple Matlab return parameters back into a list of .NET doubles.
               /// </summary>
               /// <param name="toList">MWArray variable, returned from Matlab code.</param>
               /// <returns>List of .NET doubles.</returns>
               public static List<double> MyToDoubleList(this MWArray toList)
               {
                   var matNumericArray = toList;
                   var netArray = (MWNumericArray)matNumericArray.ToArray();

                   var result = new List<double>();
                   // Console.Write("{0}", netArray[1]);
                   for (int i = 1; i <= netArray.NumberOfElements; i++) // Matlab arrays are 1-based, thus the odd indexing.
                   {
                       result.Add(netArray[i].ToScalarDouble());
                   }
                   return result;
               }
               /// <summary>
               /// Converts an array that contains multiple Matlab return parameters back into a list of .NET ints.
               /// </summary>
               /// <param name="toList">MWArray variable, returned from Matlab code.</param>
               /// <returns>List of .NET ints.</returns>
               public static List<int> MyToMWNumericArray(this MWArray toList)
               {
                   var matNumericArray = toList;
                   var netArray = (MWNumericArray)matNumericArray.ToArray();

                   var result = new List<int>();
                   // Console.Write("{0}", netArray[1]);
                   for (int i = 1; i <= netArray.NumberOfElements; i++) // Matlab arrays are 1-based, thus the odd indexing.
                   {
                       result.Add(netArray[i].ToScalarInteger());
                   }
                   return result;
               }
               /// <summary>
               /// Converts an int[] array into a Matlab parameters.
               /// </summary>
               /// <param name="intArray">MWArray variable, returned from Matlab code.</param>
               /// <returns>List of .NET ints.</returns>
               public static MWNumericArray MyToMWNumericArray(this int[] intArray)
               {
                   return new MWNumericArray(1, intArray.Length, intArray); // rows, columns int[] realData
               }
               /// <summary>
               /// Converts an double[] array into parameter for a Matlab call.
               /// </summary>
               /// <param name="arrayOfDoubles">Array of doubles.</param>
               /// <returns>MWNumericArray suitable for passing into a Matlab call.</returns>
               public static MWNumericArray MyToMWNumericArray(this double[] arrayOfDoubles)
               {
                   return new MWNumericArray(1, arrayOfDoubles.Length, arrayOfDoubles); // rows, columns int[] realData
               }
               /// <summary>
               /// Converts an List of doubles into a parameter for a Matlab call.
               /// </summary>
               /// <param name="listOfDoubles">List of doubles.</param>
               /// <returns>MWNumericArray suitable for passing into a Matlab call.</returns>
               public static MWNumericArray MyToMWNumericArray(this List<double> listOfDoubles)
               {
                   return new MWNumericArray(1, listOfDoubles.Count, listOfDoubles.ToArray()); // rows, columns int[] realData
               }
               /// <summary>
               /// Converts a list of some type into an array of the same type.
               /// </summary>
               /// <param name="toArray">List of some type.</param>
               /// <returns>Array of some type.</returns>
               public static T[] MyToArray<T>(this List<T> toArray)
               {
                   var copy = new T[toArray.Count];
                   for (int i = 0; i < toArray.Count; i++) {
                       copy[i] = toArray[i];
                   }
                   return copy;
               }
               static private readonly MatlabGraph.Graph MatlabInstance = new MatlabGraph.Graph();
               /// <summary>
               /// Plot a 2D graph.
               /// </summary>
               /// <param name="x">Array of doubles, x axis.</param>
               /// <param name="y">Array of doubles, y axis.</param>
               /// <param name="title">Title of plot.</param>
               /// <param name="xaxis">X axis label.</param>
               /// <param name="yaxis">Y axis label.</param>
               static public void MyGraph2D(List<double> x, List<double> y, string title = "title", string xaxis = "xaxis", string yaxis = "yaxis")
               {
                   MatlabInstance.Graph2D(x.MyToMWNumericArray(), y.MyToMWNumericArray(), title, xaxis, yaxis);
               }
               /// <summary>
               /// Plot a 2D graph.
               /// </summary>
               /// <param name="x">Array of doubles, x axis.</param>
               /// <param name="y">Array of doubles, y axis.</param>
               /// <param name="title">Title of plot.</param>
               /// <param name="xaxis">X axis label.</param>
               /// <param name="yaxis">Y axis label.</param>
               static public void MyGraph2D(double[] x, double[] y, string title = "title", string xaxis = "xaxis", string yaxis = "yaxis")
               {
                   MatlabInstance.Graph2D(x.MyToMWNumericArray(), y.MyToMWNumericArray(), title, xaxis, yaxis);
               }
               /// <summary>
               /// Unit test for this class. Displays a graph using Matlab.
               /// </summary>
               static public void Unit()
               {
                   {
                       var x = new double[100];
                       var y = new double[100];
                       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                           x[i] = i;
                           y[i] = Math.Sin(i);
                       }
                       MyGraph2D(x, y);                
                   }

                   {
                       var x = new double[100];
                       var y = new double[100];
                       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                           x[i] = i;
                           y[i] = 2 ^ i;
                       }
                       MyGraph2D(x, y);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       ```
7. Next, we export a .m file into a .NET assembly. I used Matlab 2010a (this will work for 2010b also). Use Matlab, 32-bit version (32-bit or 64-bit is displayed in the splash screen when Matlab starts up).

   2. The following Matlab code displays a graph. Save it as  `Graph2D.m`.

      ```
      function Graph2D (x,y, titleTop, labelX, labelY)

      % Create figure
      myNewFigure = figure;

      plot(x,y)

      title({titleTop});
      xlabel({labelX});
      ylabel({labelY});
      ```
   3. Test this within Matlab by typing the following at the console (make sure you change  `Current Folder`  in the Matlab toolbar to the same directory as `Graph2D.m`):

      ```
      x = 0:.2:20;
      y = sin(x)./sqrt(x+1);
      Graph2D(x,y,'myTitle', 'my x-axis', 'my y-axis')
      ```
   4. In the Matlab deployment tool, add a class  `Graph` , and add the file  `Graph2D.m` , then package it into  `MatlabGraph.dll`  (change the component name to  `MatlabGraph`  in settings, this determines the name of the generated .dll).
   5. In your .NET project, add a reference to  `MatlabGraph.dll`  (the .NET .dll we have just compiled from  `Graph2D.m` ). This will be  `32-bit`  if its compiled with the  `32-bit`  release of Matlab.
   6. In your .NET project, add a reference to the 32-bit version of `MWArray.dll`. You can find this by searching the Matlab install directory.
   7. Again, make sure that everything is either consistently  `32-bit`, or consistently  `64-bit`.

      9. If you choose  `32-bit` , your .NET app must be compiled for  `x32`, you must use the  `32-bit`  version of Matlab (it will show  `32-bit`  in the splash screen) to export the .NET .dll, and you must import the  `32-bit`  version of `MWArray.dll`  into your .NET project.
      10. If you choose  `64-bit` , compile your .NET app into  `All CPU`, you must use the  `64-bit`  version of Matlab (it will show  `64-bit`  in the splash screen) to export the .NET .dll, and you must import the  `64-bit`  version of  `MWArray.dll`  into your .NET project.
   8. Run the .NET app, and it will display the graph above, by calling the Matlab runtimes.
8. If you want to deploy this to a new PC, you will have to install the .NET runtimes on this PC (these are royalty free).
9. The nice thing about this is that you can customize the graphs in Matlab to your hearts content, using all the power of Matlab. You could do 3-D graphs: create a new figure in Matlab using  `File..New..Figure`, customize it using  `Insert`, then generate the .m code using  `File..Generate M file`. Its fairly obvious what the lines in the newly generated .m file do, you can copy them into your original  `Graph2D.m`  file, then regenerate  `MatlabGraph.dll`. For example, adding a title to the figure adds a line `title({'My new title});` to the auto-generated .m file.
10. If there is any interest, I can provide the complete C# sample project in .NET.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it's been a great help, but do you know anyway to integrate this plot in the windows app, I mean to show it inside the window , not as pop out window? like and ActiveX or Dll?

Comment: This answer was created to avoid the need to plot graphs within WinForms. If you have a WinForms environment, then Matlab is not really the way to go, instead see graphing methods designed for WinForms at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837087/c-sharp-winform-chart. Since then, I've actually switched to doing all of my analysis in R as its a lot easier compared to doing it in C# then calling graphs in Matlab.

Comment: +1 useful information.  Fabulous detailing of steps to solve problem.

Comment: Jesus! You should really take a .NET library and do everything right in C#! See: http://ilnumerics.net

Comment: I want to ask you for a favor please, I don't have the Matlab Builder NE, so can you please provide the "MatlabGraph.dll" file, for a simple function Graph2D like the one you are giving in your example, i will be thankful.

Comment: It worked like magic! Thank you. But, I could not make it work on a machine without a matlab installation, even with all referenced dlls on the same folder of the executable, I got System.TypeInitializationException on a clear vm inside my working machine. Am I missing something?

Comment: By the way, both machines are Win7 x64, project compiled with .net 4.0 target x64, dll created using x64 Matlab, used dlls: MWArray.dll, WebFiguresService.dll, MatlabGraph.dll, MatlabGraphNative.dll

Comment: @sweaver2112 The numbering was fine when I created the answer, I think a SO upgrade might have shifted things. It's a community Wiki - please feel free to correct!